# Use of cvcomputer or cvdoubleitem

Tags: moderncv

I have a cosmetic question. I am wondering how I could center the two words in the red circle.

[image]

Basically I would like to have either:

"Système d'exploitation" in one line

or,

"Système" and "d'exploitation", one above the other but centered. Not rightflushed like in the example.

```
\section{Compétences}
\subsection{Langues \hspace{6cm} Informatique}
\cvcomputer{Anglais}{Courant (En poste depuis février 2014 au Royaume-Uni)}{Language}{C, Matlab}
\cvcomputer{Espagnol}{Bon niveau}{Système d'exploitation}{Microsoft office, Linux}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but 'microsoft office' isn't an operating system ;)

Comment: We need to be able to reproduce the problem. As of now, it's difficult to recreate it without you supplying us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks Hugo to spot it! It was an irrelevant example by the way:)

Answer (score 3):

You should have a closer look to the complete layout of class `moderncv`.

To be able to see better which language name (definiens) belongs to which description of skills (definiendum) the complete layout is based on the fact that the first column is right justified, the second left justified.

That makes a very clear structure of the document and is the reason why I like the layout of class `moderncv`.

What you want does disturb the harmony of the layout.  So please don't do it.

BTW: mixing spoken languages and computer languages is not a very good idea, I think. I would never do that!

Or choose just another document class, fitting better what you need.

There are several possibilitys to get a "better" layout.  I show you some in the following MWE (based on the example file of the class, added your code snippet):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}  
%\nopagenumbers{}      

% character encoding
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} 

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, 
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, 
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, 
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, 
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, 
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, 
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, 
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, 
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}               % optional, 
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, 


\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}

%change foot symbol -- instead of textbullet
%\renewcommand*{\footsymbol}{%
  %{~--~}%
%}



\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{}{Microsoft office, Linux}{Système d'exploitation} % <=======================================
\cvitemwithcomment{Système d'exploitation}{Microsoft office, Linux}{Système d'exploitation} % <=======================================

\subsection{Languages \hspace{6cm} Informatique}
\cvcomputer{Anglais}{Courant (En poste depuis février 2014 au Royaume-Uni)}{Language}{C, Matlab}
\cvcomputer{Espagnol}{Bon niveau}{Système d'exploitation}{Microsoft office, Linux}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

and the resulting page (please see my red circle markings: wanted layout!, blue circle: better layout for you?, red cross: do not mix computer languages with spoken languages ...):

[image: second page]

If you insist in centering you can create a new command `\mycvdoubleitem` to get the layout you want.  Add the following lines in the preamble (befor `\begin{document}`):

```
\newcommand*{\mycvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\centering\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}% <========================
    \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#5\end{minipage}}}
```

In the marked line (`<=========`) I changed the layout to centered (`\centering`).

With

```
\mycvdoubleitem{Espagnol}{Bon niveau}{Système d'exploitation}{Microsoft office, Linux} % <=======================================
```

in your cv you get what you want (see red circle):

[image]